# How to Call a jQuery Function on Another jQuery Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to call a jQuery function on another jQuery function?

I am trying to refresh the contents of a div using the jQuery setInterval and load functions. So far, everything is working fine, except it loads the full div, including the div tags. I only want the contents of the div to be reloaded/refreshed. I tried adding the jQuery function `text()`, but it isn't working, or maybe I am writing up the wrong syntax.

`$('#numberOfTries').load('index.php #numberOfTries').text();` does not work.

This is what I have so far, which works but loads the entire div with the div tags:

HTML of Index.php (Top)

```
<div id="numberOfTries"><?php echo $numberOfTries; ?></div>
```

JS of Index.php (Bottom)

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#numberOfTries').load('index.php #numberOfTries');
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

The script loads the full div, which is `<div id="numberOfTries">50</div>`, but I only want to load the content of the div, which is `50`.

When the script runs, the HTML ends up looking like this:

```
<div id="numberOfTries">
<div id="numberOfTries">50</div>
</div>
```

But I only want it to look like this:

```
<div id="numberOfTries">
50
</div>
```

I think my syntax `$('#numberOfTries').load('index.php #numberOfTries').text();` is incorrect.

Please let me know if clarification is needed.

Comment: What script loads the full div?

Comment: @MelanciaUK `$('#numberOfTries').load('index.php #numberOfTries');` basically reloads `<div id="numberOfTries"><?php echo $numberOfTries; ?></div>`, but it loads the entire div like so: `<div id="numberOfTries"><div id="numberOfTries">50</div></div>`, while I only want it to load `<div id="numberOfTries">50</div>', which is only `50` the content of the div.

Comment: So basically you're loading the same page where the div is, within this div? What were you expecting then?

Comment: @MelanciaUK I am trying to reload the content of the div only, not the full div with the div tags. I looked up the jQuery text() function, but I am having trouble implementing it.

Comment: `.load()` is loading the content of the page you're passing as a parameter, but just the element which ID is `numberOfTries`, and adding it to the same div.

Comment: The problem is not with the `.text()`. You just misunderstood the use of `.load()`.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Is there anyway to clean up the div and only reload the contents of it? I want it to look like this `<div id="numberOfTries">50</div>` instead of `<div id="numberOfTries"><div id="numberOfTries">50</div></div>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the use of `.load()`.

In your call, you're loading the `index.php` page, and grabbing the element which ID is `numberOfTries` and placing it in this same `div`.

To achieve what you want to do, you'll need to use the `.load()` callback:

```
$("#numberOfTries").load("index.php #numberOfTries", function() {
  // Load the resource and look for the element.
  // When it's done, return this element .text().
  return $(this).text();
}).text();
```

[jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

As a side note, it's worth it clarifying that the `.text()` would work just fine with your example, but you would have one `div` nested within another, and worse, both sharing the same ID.

But it would work anyway: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/owce44gt/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the nested divs to ocur you could just use .replaceWith() so you'll replace the entire DIV. Maybe you've to save the success data from the .load() in a variable to do so.